# Simple maximum volume question

Tags: geometry, maxima-minima

> A person has a rectangular piece of cardboard that is 8 cm long and 6 cm wide. He cuts squares of side length $x$ centimetres from each of the corners of the cardboard:

[image]

> He turns up the sides to form an open box, as shown:

[image]

> The value for x for which the volume of the box is maximum is?

I know how to get the answer, (that is, by forming an equation for the volume and differentiating to find maximums), and I also know how to find the surface area and hence the volume, that is by simply multiplying the side lengths $(8-2x)$, $(6-2x)$ and $(x)$, but could someone please explain why my original method finding the surface area as $48-4x^2$ be incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation is correct:
$$2(8-2x)x+2(6-2x)x+(6-2x)(8-2x)=48-4x^2$$

Comment: Oh right, nevermind, I realised I stuffed up. I calculated the 'surface area', which is completely irrelevant in the calculation of volume (rather than the 'base area').